# Renormalization group in condensed physics and field theory

Tags: reference-request, discrete-dynamical-systems, difference-equations, renormalization

Renormalization group in field theory is differenct from the one in condensed physics in that the former satisfies a differential equation, but the latter does not.

Does Renormalization group in  condensed physics satisfy difference equation, or not? Any reference is appeciated.

Comment: Take 1D Ising model as an example https://bingweb.binghamton.edu/~suzuki/ThermoStatFIles/16.12%20PT%20Renormalization%20group.pdf . Coarse graining procedure leads to recursion equations for the couplings (page 6).

Comment: @CaveJohnsonc, I mean whether for every renormalization schene there is a corresponding differential equation?